# Github actions share workspace/artifacts between jobs?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

Trying to use Github's beta actions, I have two jobs, one that builds the code and then one that will deploy code. However, I can't seem to get the build artifact in deploy job.

My latest attempt is to manually set a container image with the same volumes for each job, according to docs this should be solution: https://help.github.com/en/articles/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainervolumes

> Sets an array of volumes for the container to use. You can use volumes to share data between services or other steps in a job. You can specify named Docker volumes, anonymous Docker volumes, or bind mounts on the host.

**Workflow**

```
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master
    paths:
    - .github/workflows/server.yml
    - server/*
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: docker://node:10
      volumes:
      - /workspace:/github/workspace
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - run: yarn install
      working-directory: server
    - run: yarn build
      working-directory: server
    - run: yarn test
      working-directory: server
    - run: ls
      working-directory: server
  deploy:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: docker://google/cloud-sdk:latest
      volumes:
      - /workspace:/github/workspace
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
      - run: ls
        working-directory: server
      - run: gcloud --version
```

The first job (build) has a build directory, but when the second job (deploy) runs it doesn't and only contains the source code.

*This project is a mono repo with code I'm trying to deploy being under path `server` hence all the `working-directory` flags.*

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57509118/new-github-actions-run-in-empty-folders - the [Workflow syntax docs](https://help.github.com/en/articles/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobs) say "Each job runs in a fresh instance of the virtual environment specified by runs-on." My guess (I'm not in the beta so I'm just guessing) is that your deploy job would either need to become a step in the `build` job, or would need to reproduce the `build` steps again in the new container. (Minus, perhaps, the `yarn test` step since you already know that it succeeded).

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? I'm trying to figure out how to do this as well.. From what i've read jobs are supposed to share the workspace filesystem, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @Joseph nope, I'm just running one job and using custom docker image. I believe issue sits with GitHub and is likely due to the transitioning from HCL to YML syntax. Odd that they plan to drop HCL at the end of September and the basic ability to share artefacts between jobs doesn't work yet. Hopefully, in a months time, it will be resolved.

Comment: "You can use volumes to share data between services or other steps in a job." That means sharing data within a single job between steps. It's not for sharing data between steps or workflows.

Comment: 3 years, 5 months later, and this is still not possible without using artifacts or cache.
GitHub, if you will ever read this, a simple keyword `after: <job_id>` would be amazing.

Comment: Github Actions is my source of frustration this week I don't believe they had an intent to create it for humans. Funniest thing we can find lots of beautiful pictures of workflow graphs, but no real example of implementing such pipeline without ducktape.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

You can use the Github Actions upload-artifact and download-artifact to share data between jobs.

In job1:

```
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v1

- run: mkdir -p path/to/artifact

- run: echo hello > path/to/artifact/world.txt

- uses: actions/upload-artifact@master
  with:
    name: my-artifact
    path: path/to/artifact
```

And job2:

```
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@master

- uses: actions/download-artifact@master
  with:
    name: my-artifact
    path: path/to/artifact
    
- run: cat path/to/artifact/world.txt
```

https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact
https://github.com/actions/download-artifact

Comment: you can now also delete artifacts:
https://github.com/marketplace/actions/delete-run-artifacts
https://github.com/marketplace/actions/purge-artifacts

Comment: @qmacro I'd like to do something like this, but I would like to build a Docker image that I would use in a following jobs' `services` rather than its `steps`. Don't see how that's possible, since the artifact downloading would be done only _after_ the `services` are started. Any suggestions?

Comment: while this is indeed an option, for anything serious (imagine 50 docker images shared), using this approach takes tens of minutes. Since github does not offer a proper solution, we switched to circleci, which cut the builds by at least 1 hour. its very, very weird not to have such an option

Comment: The order of the steps in 2nd job is very important. `checkout` action deletes everything :)

Answer (score 45):

For those interested in sharing a Docker image between two jobs, here is how I did it:

```
jobs:
  docker-build:
    name: Docker build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Build Docker image
        run: |
          docker build -t foo/bar:$GITHUB_SHA
          mkdir -p path/to/artifacts
          docker save foo/bar:$GITHUB_SHA > path/to/artifacts/docker-image.tar
          
      - name: Temporarily save Docker image
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: docker-artifact
          path: path/to/artifacts
          retention-days: 1

  docker-deploy:
    name: Deploy to Docker Hub
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: docker-build
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Retrieve saved Docker image
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: docker-artifact
          path: path/to/artifacts

      - name: Docker load
        run: |
          cd path/to/artifacts
          docker load < docker-image.tar
          # docker_build_push.sh
```

Very inspired by https://github.com/unfor19/install-aws-cli-action/actions/runs/400601222/workflow

Merci @unfor19

Comment: For anyone coming across this and wondering how to avoid cluttering up your artifacts since github doesn't provide an action for that: there are several community actions, e.g. https://github.com/marketplace/actions/delete-artifact

Comment: @AlanPlum Well said. We do clean up artifacts now with the parameter `retention-days`. I'll update my answer. Thanks.

Comment: this is indeed an option, but if you have many images, this is a very painful and slow option. Other CI/CD frameworks have this by default, github does not.

Comment: `retention-days` is the key! Otherwise Github gonna waste your money

Answer (score 30):

Use [Cache or Artifacts Upload/Download](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/github-actions-how-to-share-data-between-jobs-fc1547defc3e)

**Caching** is used to re-use data/files between jobs or workflows while **Artifacts** are used to save files after workflow ended.

Answer (score 26):

> ### [GitHub Actions – Artifacts v4 is now Generally Available](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-12-14-github-actions-artifacts-v4-is-now-generally-available) (Dec. 2023)
>
> We have released new versions (`v4`) of [actions/upload-artifact](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact) and [actions/download-artifact](https://github.com/actions/download-artifact).
> Customers are encouraged to update their workflows to use the `v4` artifact actions at their earliest convenience.
>
> This version of the artifact actions include performance improvements and new features, however there are also key differences from previous versions that may require updates to your workflows.
>
> - Artifacts will be scoped to a job rather than a workflow.
>   This allows the artifact to become immediately available to [download from the API](https://docs.github.com/rest/actions/artifacts#download-an-artifact) after being uploaded.
> - Multiple jobs in the same run cannot upload to the same artifact.
> - A single job can upload a maximum of 10 artifacts.
> - Artifacts `v4` is not cross-compatible with previous versions.
>   For example, an artifact uploaded using `v3` cannot be used with `actions/download-artifact@v4`.
>
> This version of artifacts is only available to GitHub.com customers today but we will be extending support to GitHub Enterprise Server (GHES) customers in the future.
>
> A blog post will be published in the new year with more details around why we made these improvements and what's coming next.
> To learn more about what is included in `v4`, visit  [actions/upload-artifact](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact/tree/main/README.md#v4---whats-new) and [actions/download-artifact](https://github.com/actions/download-artifact/tree/main/README.md#v4---whats-new) repositories.

---

If you are using the upload/download GitHub Actions, beware of the structure of the artifact.

Starting January 2020, see "[GitHub Actions: Changes to artifact download experience](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-01-14-github-actions-changes-to-artifact-download-experience/)":

> We have changed the artifact download experience in GitHub Actions so **it no longer adds an extra root directory to the downloaded archive**.
>
> Previously, if you uploaded the following files and folders as an artifact named `foo`, the downloaded archive would contain the following structure:
>
> ```
> foo/
> |-- file1.txt
> |-- dir1/
>      |-- dir1-file1.txt
> ```
>
> Now, you will get an archive that only contains the files and folders you uploaded:
>
> ```
> file1.txt
>   dir1/
>   |-- dir1-file1.txt
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Each job runs on the separate runner.

[Upload artifact action implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIqV8.png)

Github Action "**actions/upload-artifact@v3**" uploads the files from provided path to storage container location.

In next job when you run action "**actions/download-artifact@v3**" , it downloads the artifact from 'storage container location' where previous job uploaded the artifacts to provided path.

[Implementation for download artifact and displaying download path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usTKO.png)

For more information refer below links,

[Github action for upload artifacts](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact)

[Github action for download artifacts](https://github.com/actions/download-artifact)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer on using caches and the answer for docker images, here is how I got it to work:

```
  get-docker-image:
    steps:
      - name: Create cache for docker image
        uses: actions/cache@v4
        with:
          path: images
          key: image-key

      - name: Download docker image from source
        run: |
          mkdir -p images
          cd images
          docker login registry
          docker pull path/image:tag
          docker save path/image:tag | gzip > docker-image.tgz

  user-docker-image:
    needs:
      - get-docker-image
    steps:
      - name: Restore cached docker image
        uses: actions/cache/restore@v4
        with:
          path: images
          key: image-key

      - name: Use the image
        working-directory: images
        run: |
          docker load < docker-image.tgz
          // do something with the image
```

Note that using caches is expected to be somewhat faster than upload/download.