# New GitHub actions run in empty folders

Tags: github, github-actions, github-ci

I am working with new GitHub actions, idea of a workflow below is to run when pr is opened or synchronised, it should first check out and install dependencies and afterwards run few yarn scripts

```
name: PR to Master
on: 
  pull_request:
    branches:
    - master
jobs:
  # Synchronize or Opened
  synchronized_or_opened:
    name: Synchronize or Opened
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/bin/filter@master
      with:
        args: action 'opened|synchronize'
  # Add Labels
  add_labels:
    name: Add Labels
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/labeler@v2
      with:
        repo-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    needs: synchronized_or_opened
  # Checkout
  checkout:
    name: Checkout
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    needs: synchronized_or_opened
  # Install Dependencies
  install_dependencies:
    name: Install Dependencies
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x]
    steps:
    - run: yarn dep:install-npm
    needs: checkout
  # Typecheck
  typecheck:
    name: Typecheck
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x]
    steps:
    - run: yarn typecheck
    needs: install_dependencies
  # Prettier
  prettier:
    name: Prettier
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x]
    steps:
    - run: yarn prettier
    needs: install_dependencies
  # ESLint
  eslint:
    name: ESlint
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x]
    steps:
    - run: yarn eslint
    needs: install_dependencies
  # Danger
  danger:
    name: Danger
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x]
    steps:
    - run: yarn danger
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    needs: install_dependencies
```

At the moment it successfully gets to a checkout stage, but once Install job is ran I get following error

> error Couldn't find a package.json file in
>   "/home/runner/work/myRepo/myRepo"

Judging by this checkout either failed or I am in a wrong folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Workflow syntax docs](https://help.github.com/en/articles/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobs):

> Each job runs in a fresh instance of the virtual environment specified by runs-on.

From what I can see here, you're doing the checkout step in a completely separate job from others. Doing it that way it does not affect other jobs in any way. It should actually be defined *inside* those jobs where your npm CLI commands are executed.

Here's an example of how it would look like in one of your jobs:

```
jobs:
  # (...) Other jobs
  # Install Dependencies
  install_dependencies:
    name: Install Dependencies
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - run: yarn dep:install-npm
    needs: checkout
  # (...) Other jobs
```

There are some general examples in [GitHub starter workflow templates](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/master/ci/npm-publish.yml).