# github actions share workspace (yml config)

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

It would be cool if I could run a workflow that looks like the following - maybe I'm just missing a simple configuration in GitHub actions but I don't know how to share a workspace between jobs, while using `job.needs` to specify which jobs can run when others have completed successfully.

```
name: Node CI

on: [push]
env:
  CI: true

jobs:
  install:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [12.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - name: install node_modules
      run: yarn install

  lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [install]
    steps:
      - name: eslint
        run: yarn lint

  build:
    needs: [install]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: yarn build
        run: yarn build

  test:
    needs: [install, build]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: jest
        run: yarn test --coverage
```

I have read [Github actions share workspace/artifacts between jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57498605/github-actions-share-workspace-artifacts-between-jobs) but I'd rather not have to upload `node_modules` and download for every step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the actions workspace is only shared between steps of the same job. You cannot share the filesystem between jobs.

Uploading/downloading artifacts between jobs is one solution. You also could try the new [`actions/cache`](https://github.com/actions/cache) action to cache the `node_modules` directory and restore it on subsequent jobs.

```
- uses: actions/cache@v1
  with:
    path: node_modules
    key: ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
    restore-keys: |
      ${{ runner.os }}-node-
```

Note that there are currently some fairly strict limits so it may not work if you have a very large `node_modules` directory.

> Individual caches are limited to 400MB and a repository can have up to 2GB of caches. Once the 2GB limit is reached, older caches will be evicted based on when the cache was last accessed. Caches that are not accessed within the last week will also be evicted.

Comment: Note that 400MB limit is checked after compression (tar+gzip), which helps a bit.

Comment: yeah I've resorted to using `actions/cache` for now! Thanks.