# Github Actions: Multiple jobs single release

Tags: github-actions, github-release

I am having 2 jobs in the Github runner. The first job builds the android apk. The second one to build a zip file. I want to have both the apk and the zip file in the same release. But after the apk is published into a release, the zip file does not get published into the release. The error shown is:
 `Validation Failed {"resource":"Release","code":"already_exists","field":"tag_name"}`
`buid.yml`:

```
name: Build Process

on:
 push:
  tags:
   - v*

jobs:
 Build_Android:
if: "!contains(github.event.head_commit.message, 'skip-android')"
name: Build APK
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
  - name: Setup Java
    uses: actions/setup-java@v2
    with:
      distribution: "zulu"
      java-version: "12.x"

  - name: Setup Flutter
    uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
    with:
      channel: "stable"

  - name: Get Packages
    run: flutter pub get

  - name: Build APK
    run: flutter build apk --split-per-abi --release

  - name: Create Github Release
    uses: ncipollo/release-action@v1
    with:
      artifacts: "build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/*.apk"
      replacesArtifacts: false
      token: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}

Build_Windows:
if: "!contains(github.event.head_commit.message, 'skip-windows')"
name: Building zip
runs-on: windows-latest

steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
  - name: Setup Java
    uses: actions/setup-java@v2
    with:
      distribution: "zulu"
      java-version: "12.x"

  - name: Setup Flutter
    uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
    with:
      channel: "stable"

  - name: Get Packages
    run: flutter pub get

  - name: Enable windows build
    run: flutter config --enable-windows-desktop

  - name: Build Artifacts
    run: flutter build windows --release

  - name: Archive Artifacts
    uses: thedoctor0/zip-release@master
    with:
      type: "zip"
      filename: AppName-${{github.ref_name}}-windows.zip
      directory: build/windows/runner/Release

  - name: Create Github Release
    uses: ncipollo/release-action@v1
    with:
      artifacts: "build/windows/runner/Release/AppName-${{github.ref_name}}-windows.zip"
      replacesArtifacts: false
      token: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! 
Thank!

Answer (score 5):

The error says that:

`Release with this tag name already exists`

It is coming from your last step:

`ncipollo/release-action@v1`

By default this action seems to be always trying to create a new release ("This action will create a GitHub release"), but according to its documentation [here](https://github.com/ncipollo/release-action#action-inputs) you can alter that behaviour by adding:

`allowUpdates = "true"`

```
- name: Create Github Release
  uses: ncipollo/release-action@v1
  with:
    artifacts: "build/windows/runner/Release/AppName-${{github.ref_name}}-windows.zip"
    replacesArtifacts: false
    token: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
    allowUpdates: true
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try and let you know if it works!

Comment: Working fine for me...

Comment: Can you help me with this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75812715/8024296

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar situation when I wanted to publish windows and linux binaries, all in a same release. And finally I came to the conclusion that I should solve this by organizing the jobs flows. I changed my yml file so that

- I had a separate job for each deployment that only produces it's own artifacts (ex. Windows_Publish and Linux_publish jobs)
- Each of these jobs, persists it's generated artifacts. But all jobs use same name and path for it. So all artifacts would be accumulated in one place.
- I had a third job (say Deploy_Artifacts job) that restores all those artifacts and simply deploys them all at once.
- NOTE that the Deploy_Artifacts job, had to depend on both Windows_Publish and Linux_publish jobs. (needs: [Deploy_Artifacts,Windows_Publish])

I used actions/upload-artifact@master for persistence and restoring artifacts [[See]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57498605/github-actions-share-workspace-artifacts-between-jobs) and ncipollo/release-action@v1 for sending the artifacts to release. And [[this]](https://github.com/Acidmanic/static-web-server/blob/master/.github/workflows/release-by-tags.yml) is the yml file I finally came up with.