# Github action retrieve the link of the newly created artifact for release

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, artifact

I have to retrieve the link of the artifact just created to then create a release.

Can you give me a hand?

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:

name: Build  
jobs:
  install-and-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install npm dependencies
        run: |
          npm install
  build-android:
    needs: install-and-test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install npm dependencies
        run: |
          npm install
      - name: Build Android Release
        run: |
          cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
      - name: Upload Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: app-release.apk
          path: android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/
```

Answer (score -1):

> retrieve the link of the artifact just created

You can add below step to echo the artifact download URL in same workflow.

```
- name:Artifact URL
  run: echo "::set-output name=artifact_url::https://github.com/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY/suites/$GITHUB_RUN_ID/artifacts/app-release.apk"
```

In case you are looking to use uploaded artifact in same workflow or different workflow, use [actions/download-artifact](https://github.com/actions/download-artifact/tree/main) action.

Comment: Warning: The `set-output` command is deprecated and will be disabled soon. Please upgrade to using Environment Files. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/

Comment: Could you write the full code to try?