Same venv in different workflow jobs
I would like to allow two jobs to run in parallel and both use the same environment. I have attached a sample github actions .yml file with comments to better explain what I need. I am new to the community so thank you for the help in advance!
I made a simplified code with the areas I need help with below.
name: Need two jobs to run in parallel and use the same `venv` from the first job

on: push

jobs:
  install-dependency:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.11.9'

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
#         Save the VENV somehow!
          source venv/bin/activate
          pip install -r requirements.txt

  run-pytest:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [install-dependency]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4

      - name: Run Pytest
        run: |
          source ${{ insert-venv-path }}/bin/activate
          pip install pytest
          pytest --maxfail=1 --disable-warnings -v

  run-other-pytest:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [install-dependency]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4

      - name: Run Pytest
        run: |
          source ${{ insert-venv-path }}/bin/activate
          pip install pytest
          pytest --maxfail=1 --disable-warnings -v

I know github makes it so that every job runs on a different environment but I still thought this was possible. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I guess you can copy-paste the virtual environment's directory from one job to another as artifact: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57498605

All jobs in a workflow run on a different and clean runner. This is to prevent polluting your environment, file system, etc by changes from other/previous jobs.
The only way to share file system from install-dependency job is for it to upload a zip file of venv directory using
- uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
  with:
    name: venv
    path: ./venv

and then download it in each of the other jobs and activate:
- uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
  with:
    name: venv
    path: ./venv
- name: Activate
  run: source venv/bin/activate

Here is the complete workflow:
name: venv

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  install-dependency:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.11.9'

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
          python -m pip install requests

      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: venv
          path: ./venv

  run-pytest:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [install-dependency]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.11.9'

      - uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: venv
          path: ./venv

      - name: Activate
        run: source venv/bin/activate


  run-other-pytest:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [install-dependency]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.11.9'

      - uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: venv
          path: ./venv

      - name: Activate
        run: source venv/bin/activate


I attempted to do that and it did upload but when I try to retrieve it fails:
Run source venv/bin/activate
  source venv/bin/activate
  pip install pytest
  pytest --maxfail=1 --disable-warnings -v
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
/home/runner/work/_temp/7082cdf0-8878-4ea5-a839-fa9bdd9b33b2.sh: line 1: venv/bin/activate: No such file or directory
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Any chance you could upload a simple example of a working version?

See update answer

The workflow above does work however it takes a very long time. Due to zipping and unzipping thousands of files in a venv.
